# change default port 8080 maven gae goal appengine:devserver

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, port, maven-3

I'm having a problem, probably is quite simple but I did not find the solution yet.

I'm trying to launch my local GAE server (through Run-configurations of Eclipse) on a specific port (8888 in my case) but it starts only at default port 8080 and after trying with different options ... I'm not lucky

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Run this from the cmd line: `mvn help:describe -Dcmd=appengine:devserver -Ddetail` - you'll see all the available options for `appengine:devserver` goal.

The one that you want is:

`mvn appengine:devserver -Dappengine.port=8888`

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Plugin for eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) (GPE) allows you to specify the port number on the second tab ('Server') in a run configuration.

If you're not using that (which you probably should be) you can configure the port in your pom directly like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gae.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>8080</port>
        <address>0.0.0.0</address>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: According to the documentation at: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/maven it is now <port>8080</port>
          <host>0.0.0.0</host>
          <admin_host>0.0.0.0</admin_host>

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Have you tried adding the `--port 8888` option to your run configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart

It seems that the documentation has changed:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/maven

Use `<host>` instead of `<address>`

Here is how you bind the host address for Docker:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
    <port>8080</port>
    <host>0.0.0.0</host>
    <admin_host>0.0.0.0</admin_host>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```